# AngularJS - error message on drop down window like html5 validation

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented AngularJs validation as below :-

```
   <input type="number" min="0" max="100" style="width:80px;" ng-model="admin.preSourceThreshold" name="preSourceThreshold" ng-class="{red: preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$invalid && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty}" required> %
            <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.number && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty">Must Be Number!</span>
            <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.max && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty">Number Should Be Less Then 100</span>
            <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.min && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty">Number Should Be greater Then 0</span>
            <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.required && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty">Must Be Number</span>
```

But as the user start typing in the Textbox, Error Msg gets displayed below the text box which doesn't look good.

How to show error msg like html5 required mesg in drop down under the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Angular can actually manipulate HTML5's validation popup.  It is a little involved but pretty powerful.  You can learn how here:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

You can use the ng-blur attribute to set an additional variable to check against after the input loses focus.

```
<input ng-blur="blurred=true" type="number" min="0" max="100" style="width:80px;" ng-model="admin.preSourceThreshold" name="preSourceThreshold" ng-class="{red: preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$invalid && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty}" required> %
        <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.number && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty">Must Be Number!</span>
        <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.max && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty && blurred">Number Should Be Less Then 100</span>
        <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.min && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty && blurred">Number Should Be greater Then 0</span>
        <span  style="color:red" ng-show="preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$error.required && preSourceThresholdForm.preSourceThreshold.$dirty && blurred">Must Be Number</span>
```

The other solution would be to not do validation until they click a button.

Example here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/b0d6IEymEnqj5hqRThNo?p=preview

Comment: will it come as popup under textbox?

Comment: It will work just like before, it just won't fire until after they click out of it.

Comment: what do you mean popup? 
See the plnkr.

Comment: Have u seen the html5 required validation will come under text box as popup please fill the value like that i am asking.

Comment: I would do it the way it's shown in the link I posted.  See above.  That will give you the cleanest effect I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the one what you are expectiing.
But it's a nice one so , I would like to post this and all can implement this new thing that AngularJs provides.

AngularJS provides xtForm directive which provides a better performance and experience for the form validation .
I'm sharing this link with all so that we coul learn more about the AngularJs.
http://www.brentmckendrick.com/code/xtform/